# Quartz scheduler thorntail

Tags: thorntail

I am new to thorntail. I have integrated quartz in thorntail and able to hit it as REST API. But can I store the scheduler information in context so that scheduler runs once the application is up instead of hitting a URL to run it?
Please correct me if I am wrong .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question doesn't have much details, but if I understand you correctly, you want to run some code when the application starts. There are at least these 2 ways how to do it:

1. Using CDI, create an `@ApplicationScoped` bean with an observer for the `@Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class)` event:

   ```
   @ApplicationScoped
   public class Initializer {
       public void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object event) {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   This requires the `io.thorntail:cdi` fraction.
2. Using EJB, create a `@Singleton @Startup` EJB and add a `@PostConstruct` method:

   ```
   @Singleton
   @Startup
   public class Initializer {
       @PostConstruct
       public void init() {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   This requires the `io.thorntail:ejb` fraction.

I assume you already use CDI, so the 1st variant is probably preferable.